# basic_stringstream error when use boost in g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, boost, linker, g++

my below test code works fine in visual studio

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/math/distributions/normal.hpp>
int main()
{
    boost::math::normal_distribution<> norm;
    std::cout << cdf(norm, 1.96) << std::endl;
    std::cout << cdf(norm, 0.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

however, when I switch to vscode and g++, I get below error when run the exe. The build does not have error

The original error message is in Chinese. I have attempted to translate it into English.

> main.exe - cannot find the entrance
>
> cannot defined entrance _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev dynamic linking library D:\project_CPP\test\main.exe 上。

My g++ vscode config

.vscode\tasks.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "E:\\codelibrarry\\g++64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I",
                "E:\\codelibrarry\\boost_1_80_0",
                "-L",
                "E:\\codelibrarry\\boost_1_80_0\\libs",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

The built console output

E:\codelibrarry\g++64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g D:\project_CPP\test\main.cpp -I E:\codelibrarry\boost_1_80_0 -L E:\codelibrarry\boost_1_80_0\libs -o D:\project_CPP\test\main.exe

Build finished successfully.

Comment: Please show the whole `.vscode\tasks.json`.

Answer (score 0):

ok I solved the problem....

copy libstdc++-6.dll from g++/bin path to the exe path will work

But much appreciate if someone can tell me why this is required under g++ but not visual studio compiler